# How to create a column in a data frame that contains part of a string?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in my data frame named Sentence containing words and then the name of a state. 
I'm interested in getting only the name of the State and create a separate column with those only.

So far I have done this:

```
Pattern = paste0(paste0(".*\\b(", paste0(state.name, collapse="|")), ")\\b.*")

df$state = sub(Pattern, "\\1", df$Sentence)
```

The problem is Virginia is a state, but so is West Virginia.

First example:
Sentence[1] = I live in West Virginia.

Second example:
Sentence[2] = I went to Virginia once.

For both examples, my code will take the word "Virginia" and add it to the state column.

In other words, the word "West Virginia" will never be added.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sentence = c('I live in West Virginia.', 'I went to Virginia once.'),
  Result = c('West Virginia', 'Virginia'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

#                   Sentence        Result
# 1 I live in West Virginia. West Virginia
# 2 I went to Virginia once.      Virginia
```

Comment: Please read instructions at top of [tag:r] page regarding instructions for posting.

Comment: make a new variable to use for state names with a negative look-behind instead of `state.name`: `sn <- replace(state.name, state.name == 'Virginia', '(?<!West )Virginia')` and add `perl = TRUE` to your `sub`

Comment: @rawr the sentence could also be: "I live in Virginia" and in that case I want the word "Virginia" to be added to the state column. I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: yes I tried that case with my suggestion, did you?

Comment: @rawr that's weird. It works! Not sure I get the logic behind though.

Comment: it replaces "Virginia" with "Virginia not proceeded by West " (with a space)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the various search strings with a `|` as below. I've found that `stringi::stri_extract_all` will automatically give you the longest match incase of multiple hits.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Sentence = c('I live in West Virginia.', 'I went to Virginia once.'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df
#>                   Sentence
#> 1 I live in West Virginia.
#> 2 I went to Virginia once.
r <- paste(state.name,collapse = '|')

r
#> [1] "Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming"
library(stringi)

df$State <- unlist(stri_extract_all(df$Sentence,regex = r))

df
#>                   Sentence         State
#> 1 I live in West Virginia. West Virginia
#> 2 I went to Virginia once.      Virginia
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>